# querySelector works but querySelectorAll doesn't

Tags: javascript, queryselector

I'm very new to JS. 
There are 3 svgs, and I'm trying to change the fill color when the mouse is over.
When I use querySelector('.svg'), the first one works perfectly. 
I'd like to change all three of them, not only the first one, 
but none of querySelectorAll('.svg'), or getElementsbyClassName, getElementsbyTagName seem to work. What is the problem?
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

```js
const icon = document.querySelectorAll(".svg");


icon.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
  icon.style.color = "#ED4264";
});

icon.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
  icon.style.color = "black";
});
```

```html
<footer>
      <div class="prev">
        <svg
          class="svg"
          width="22"
          height="21"
          viewBox="0 0 22 21"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <path
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            clip-rule="evenodd"
            d="M10.3376 20.7849L0.183247 10.5454L10.3376 0.305979L13.1778 3.12258L7.80002 8.54544L21.9751 8.54544V12.5454L7.80002 12.5454L13.1778 17.9683L10.3376 20.7849Z"
            fill="currentcolor"
          />
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div class="random">
        <svg
          class="svg"
          width="27"
          height="24"
          viewBox="0 0 27 24"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <path
            d="M0 0L3.57143 3.57143L7.7486e-05 7.14286"
            transform="translate(20.5713 2)"
            stroke="currentcolor"
            stroke-width="3"
          />
          <path
            d="M0 0L3.57143 3.57143L7.7486e-05 7.14286"
            transform="translate(20.5713 14.8572)"
            stroke="currentcolor"
            stroke-width="3"
          />
          <path
            d="M0 12.3214C5.03247 12.3214 10.0649 9.91071 11.5747 6.16059C13.0844 2.41047 17.1104 7.37802e-05 22.1429 0"
            transform="translate(0.571289 18.4285) scale(1 -1)"
            stroke="currentcolor"
            stroke-width="4"
          />
          <path
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            clip-rule="evenodd"
            d="M22.1431 4C19.2583 4 16.9155 4.88867 15.3193 6.28589C14.4653 5.53833 13.8252 4.64478 13.4302 3.66406C13.3286 3.41235 13.2163 3.16724 13.0933 2.92822C15.4746 1.03613 18.6689 0 22.1431 0V4ZM13.0933 9.64331C11.9321 8.7207 10.9639 7.59473 10.251 6.28589C10.0537 6.64795 9.87598 7.02393 9.71924 7.41357C9.68506 7.49829 9.64844 7.58276 9.6084 7.66675C10.7573 8.46265 11.7734 9.43262 12.5425 10.5715C12.7437 10.2737 12.9277 9.96436 13.0933 9.64331ZM9.6084 13.4763C9.09961 12.4043 8.12012 11.3911 6.73145 10.5715C6.55762 10.6741 6.37744 10.7737 6.19092 10.8701C4.41309 11.7878 2.21338 12.3215 0 12.3215V16.3215C2.81885 16.3215 5.65186 15.6497 8.02588 14.4246C8.57275 14.1423 9.10352 13.8262 9.6084 13.4763Z"
            transform="translate(0.571289 3.57129)"
            fill="currentcolor"
          />
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div class="next">
        <svg
          class="svg"
          width="23"
          height="21"
          viewBox="0 0 23 21"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <path
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            clip-rule="evenodd"
            d="M12.2088 0.0202637L22.3631 10.2597L12.2088 20.4992L9.36858 17.6826L14.7464 12.2597H0.571289V8.25973H14.7464L9.36858 2.83686L12.2088 0.0202637Z"
            fill="currentcolor"
          />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: An array/DOM collection doesn't have an `addEventListener` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `.querySelector()` selects just 1 element while `.querySelectorAll()` selects multiple, that means you get a list with `.querySelectorAll()` so you need to loop through and add for each SVG an event listener

```js
const icons = document.querySelectorAll(".svg"); //use "icons", its plural

icons.forEach(icon => {   
   icon.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
     icon.style.color = "#ED4264";
   });

   icon.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
     icon.style.color = "black";
   });
})
```

```html
<footer>
      <div class="prev">
        <svg
          class="svg"
          width="22"
          height="21"
          viewBox="0 0 22 21"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <path
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            clip-rule="evenodd"
            d="M10.3376 20.7849L0.183247 10.5454L10.3376 0.305979L13.1778 3.12258L7.80002 8.54544L21.9751 8.54544V12.5454L7.80002 12.5454L13.1778 17.9683L10.3376 20.7849Z"
            fill="currentcolor"
          />
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div class="random">
        <svg
          class="svg"
          width="27"
          height="24"
          viewBox="0 0 27 24"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <path
            d="M0 0L3.57143 3.57143L7.7486e-05 7.14286"
            transform="translate(20.5713 2)"
            stroke="currentcolor"
            stroke-width="3"
          />
          <path
            d="M0 0L3.57143 3.57143L7.7486e-05 7.14286"
            transform="translate(20.5713 14.8572)"
            stroke="currentcolor"
            stroke-width="3"
          />
          <path
            d="M0 12.3214C5.03247 12.3214 10.0649 9.91071 11.5747 6.16059C13.0844 2.41047 17.1104 7.37802e-05 22.1429 0"
            transform="translate(0.571289 18.4285) scale(1 -1)"
            stroke="currentcolor"
            stroke-width="4"
          />
          <path
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            clip-rule="evenodd"
            d="M22.1431 4C19.2583 4 16.9155 4.88867 15.3193 6.28589C14.4653 5.53833 13.8252 4.64478 13.4302 3.66406C13.3286 3.41235 13.2163 3.16724 13.0933 2.92822C15.4746 1.03613 18.6689 0 22.1431 0V4ZM13.0933 9.64331C11.9321 8.7207 10.9639 7.59473 10.251 6.28589C10.0537 6.64795 9.87598 7.02393 9.71924 7.41357C9.68506 7.49829 9.64844 7.58276 9.6084 7.66675C10.7573 8.46265 11.7734 9.43262 12.5425 10.5715C12.7437 10.2737 12.9277 9.96436 13.0933 9.64331ZM9.6084 13.4763C9.09961 12.4043 8.12012 11.3911 6.73145 10.5715C6.55762 10.6741 6.37744 10.7737 6.19092 10.8701C4.41309 11.7878 2.21338 12.3215 0 12.3215V16.3215C2.81885 16.3215 5.65186 15.6497 8.02588 14.4246C8.57275 14.1423 9.10352 13.8262 9.6084 13.4763Z"
            transform="translate(0.571289 3.57129)"
            fill="currentcolor"
          />
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div class="next">
        <svg
          class="svg"
          width="23"
          height="21"
          viewBox="0 0 23 21"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <path
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            clip-rule="evenodd"
            d="M12.2088 0.0202637L22.3631 10.2597L12.2088 20.4992L9.36858 17.6826L14.7464 12.2597H0.571289V8.25973H14.7464L9.36858 2.83686L12.2088 0.0202637Z"
            fill="currentcolor"
          />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But can you please explain what does (icon => )  stands for? I know the literal meaning of =>, but I don't understand the usage in this code.

Comment: thats an arrow function. you can read here about it you will see it very often https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions The regular function way is `function(icon){...})`

Comment: @user13670138 what i do here i loop over each element in the list thats why its called `forEach` and add for each element in the list an event Listener to it

Answer (score 1):

The following returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) of elements.

```
const icon = document.querySelectorAll(".svg");
```

You can't use `addEventListener` on a node list, but you can do this:

```
icon.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener(...);
});
```

This should attach an event listener to each element of your original query.